# Why do I get NullpointerException in performTraversals for Genymotion emulator?

Tags: android, genymotion

This the second time I encounter this issue on Genymotion (on normal device it works fine). always when I open soft keyboard. People reported that on some custom rom devices it crashes as well:

```
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1427)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-29 07:14:59.912: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the first time it happened when i set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" for activity that I was opening. It crashed immediately after I opened keyboard.

Now similar thing is happening when I tap on EditText. Why might that be?

**AFTER SOME TIME...**

ok, so I figured this one out or at least I found a workaround. It stopped crashing as soon as I cleared app data from keyboard app. Simply go to settings > all > android keyboard > clear data.

Ok, but how about if this happens on users phone? how to aproach it then?